# Large SSRS HTML Report: How much HTML can browsers handle?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, reporting-services

We have a SSRS report we are rendering to HTML and inserting onto an intranet page using the JQuery ajax() function.  The size of the HTML from SSRS can be quite large--anywhere from **50KB to 200MB**.  There is always about ~20k of CSS styles passed in with the report HTML.

When displaying a 1MB report, the browser starts to slow down (scrolling up and down the page becomes 'laggy'), and above 5MB it seems unusable.  Our users are all using IE 7/8.

I'm guessing that the performance issue is a simple problem of too many DOM objects on the page and too many styles.

**Is there a rule-of-thumb on how much HTML browsers can handle comfortably?**

*Edit: Our requirements specifically disallow pagination.*

Comment: Not really. It varies depending on the browser and the hardware it runs on.

Comment: there is no rule, or rule of thumb. If you write 200mb of data the client will recieve 200mb. But it depends what you do with the data on the client side. But a rule of thumb through out any programming language is. SMALL IS BEST :) so keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browser is used for displaying content which can be read by human. Let's suppose that google provide you list of all web sities and you have to manually search throughout them. I think that you should provide users with some search criteria and pagination.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice if we could just use pagination.  Unfortunately our requirements state that we can not.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just placing links to these reports on your intranet html page, so that they can be downloaded using right-click-save-as...?

As a user I would be pretty angry if your intranet page unexpectedly bogs down my browser by inserting millions of dom nodes in an html document (and I'm sure your boss will go crazy if you kill his online sodoku session with your ajax attack:).

If you linked the reports with a meaningful caption that also includes their file sizes, thinks would be much nicer for your users.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, and there aren't a lot of possible parameters to account for, it might be worth looking into creating a batch process to pre-render the reports in .pdf format using the reporting services web service; then provide a link to the pre-rendered .pdf on the web page.  The .pdf file sizes should also be much smaller.